# HP ProBook 6560b randomly powers off

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I'm running an HP ProBook 6560b i7 laptop running Windows 7 Ultimate x64, I've been using it often and every now and then with no pattern or notice it will shut off. It registers an unexpected kernel power down in the event viewer, but I don't know what other information I can provide, and I cannot find a solution. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Running on AC adapter or batteries? Has anything been physically moved or shaken? Does this occur at any time, or only after long use (i.e. could it be overheating)? Have you tried disk check or RAM test?

Comment: Checked the Ram and the Disk. Tried two seperate AC adapters, tried a dock using the same two seperate adapters, nothing has been shaken to my knowledge. It does not happen at set time and it can happen anywhere from 30 minutes of being on, or not at all.

Comment: If it takes at least 30 minutes of use before it shuts off, it's likely *overheating*. Download a utility such as RealTemp or an alternative (http://alternativeto.net/software/real-temp/) and check it. If so, clean up ports and remove dust.

Comment: I cleaned the ports, It hasn't done the shutdown issue for a few days now, and temperatures seem normal? Clock speed seems to jump around though, is that unusual?

Comment: Irrelevant -- the system may set clock speed based on CPU load. If it's not overheating now, and otherwise operating normally, it's OK.